What classes should be included in the Model layer in the MVVM architecture
I'm a newbie in Android development. As I studied Android development in depth, I began to learn about the two major architectures commonly used in Android development: MVP and MVVM.
But after I migrated from MVP to MVVM, I found that the MVVM architecture didn't seem to be as easy to learn as an MVP, because there are many new things that come with the MVVM architecture, such as compose, LiveData, LifeCycle...
But now I have a puzzled question: what classes should be included in the model layer in the MVVM architecture? I have seen many previous MVVM architecture cases, which need to include a repository layer for requesting and storing data, does this mean that the view model can directly get data from its corresponding repository layer?
Or do you need an XxxModel layer to get data from the repository layer and hand it off to the view model layer? It's like this
class CategoriesModel {
    companion object {
        fun getCategories(
            successCallBack: (categoriesBean: CategoriesBean) -> Unit,
            emptyCallback: () -> Unit,
            errorCallBack: () -> Unit
        ) {
            CategoriesRepository.getCategoriesData(successCallBack,emptyCallback,errorCallBack)
        }
    }

}

class CategoriesRepository {

    companion object {
        private val apiInterface = RetrofitCreator.getApiInterface()
        var categoriesBean: CategoriesBean? = null

        
        fun getCategoriesData(
            successCallBack: (categoriesBean: CategoriesBean) -> Unit,
            emptyCallback: () -> Unit,
            errorCallBack: () -> Unit
        ) {
            val task = apiInterface?.getCategories()
            task?.enqueue(object : Callback<CategoriesBean> {
                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<CategoriesBean>,
                    response: Response<CategoriesBean>
                ) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        LogUtils.d(this@Companion, "HTTP_OK")
                        LogUtils.d(this@Companion, "response-->${response.body()?.data}")
                        categoriesBean = response.body()
                        categoriesBean.let { currentCategoriesBean ->
                            if (currentCategoriesBean == null || currentCategoriesBean.data.isEmpty()) {
                               
                                emptyCallback()
                            } else {
                                
                                successCallBack(categoriesBean!!)
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        LogUtils.d(
                            this@Companion,
                            "response.code()-->${response.code()}"
                        )
                        
                        errorCallBack()
                    }
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<CategoriesBean>, t: Throwable) {
                    LogUtils.d(this@Companion, "onFailure-->${t.message}")
                    errorCallBack()
                }
            })
        }

    }
}

I would appreciate it if you could answer my questions!
